# how to select top 1 from each group after order by

Tags: .net, linq, t-sql

I have 3 columns/fields as part of a generic list:  `strID, seq, unit`
there are a  bunch of `strID`s that belong to the same unit and they each have a different `seq`.  I'm interested in the row that has the minimum `seq` per `unit`(the leader of the group).  How would I accomplish this with a LINQ query (a tsql query would also be fine)?

Following is example data:

```
  strID, seq, unit
    aaa, 3, 1
    bbb, 2, 1
    ccc, 4, 1
    ddd, 8, 2
    eee, 15,2
    fff, 7, 2
```

My query would get me the following:

```
leaderID, unit
bbb, 1
fff, 2
```

Comment: Dunno about LINQ, but this is a ROW_NUMBER thing (assuming SQL Server 2005+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
select x.strID, a.unit
  from (select unit, MIN(seq) as seq from myTable group by unit) a
  join myTable x 
    on a.unit = x.unit and a.seq = x.seq
```

Comment: You do not need a self join of the table, use a window function (see my post below).

Comment: The window function may make more sense to you, but I think this is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 5):

```
source
  .GroupBy(row => row.unit)
  .Select(g => g.OrderBy(row => row.seq).First());
```

Answer (score 4):

In T-SQL, you would use

```
SELECT leaderID, unit
FROM (
    SELECT strID, unit, row_number() over(partition by unit order by seq asc) as ranking_within_unit
    FROM t
     )
WHERE ranking_within_unit = 1
```

The window functions (`OVER()`) are made for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
set nocount on
go
WITH MyTable AS
(  
SELECT 'aaa' [strID], 3 seq, 1 unit
UNION SELECT 'bbb', 2, 1
UNION SELECT 'ccc', 4, 1
UNION SELECT 'ddd', 8, 2
UNION SELECT 'eee', 15,2
UNION SELECT 'fff', 7, 2
)
,
MinSequence AS
(
    SELECT Unit, Min (Seq) MinSequence
    FROM MyTable
    Group BY Unit
)
SELECT MT.*
FROM MyTable MT
    JOIN MinSequence MS
        ON MT.Unit = MS.Unit
        AND MT.Seq = MS.MinSequence
```

results in

```
strID seq         unit
----- ----------- -----------
bbb   2           1
fff   7           2
```